# What is a good approach to get rid of dependency on a StreamReader/FileStream for Unit Tests?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

Here's the scenario:

I have a method that reads in a file via a FileStream and a StreamReader in .NET. I would like to unit test this method and somehow remove the dependency on the StreamReader object.

Ideally I would like to be able to supply my own string of test data instead of using a real file. Right now the method makes use of the StreamReader.ReadLine method throughout. What is an approach to modifying the design I have now in order to make this test possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depend on `Stream` and `TextReader` instead. Then your unit tests can use `MemoryStream` and `StringReader`. (Or load resources from inside your test assembly if necessary.)

Note how [`ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readline.aspx) is originally declared by `TextReader`, *not* `StreamReader`.

Comment: But wouldn´t this only suspend the problem? Any class that uses the "reader class" would then need to create the `StreamReader` or `TextReader`, or do I miss something?

Comment: @royalTS: They could use *any* `TextReader` and `Stream` implementation though. In tests it could be a `StringReader`; in the real code it could be a `StreamReader` wrapping a file, or a network stream etc. (It's not clear from the question whether the OP really needs both a `Stream` *and* a `TextReader`, or just a `TextReader`.) But the point is that by moving up the abstraction layer, you get more flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be to have the method accept a Stream as a parameter instead of opening its own FileStream. Your actual code could pass in the FileStream as usual, while your test method could either use a different FileStream for test data, or a MemoryStream filled up with what you wanted to test (that wouldn't require a file).

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, I'd say this is a great opportunity to investigate the merits of [Dependency Injection](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/34066).

You might want to consider redesigning your method so that it takes a delegate that returns the file's contents. One delegate (the production one) might use the classes in System.IO, while the second one (for unit testing), returns the contents directly as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is to dependency inject the TextReader and mock it for unit testing. I think you can only mock the TextReader because it is an abstract class.

```
public class FileParser
{
    private readonly TextReader _textReader;

    public FileParser(TextReader reader)
    {
        _textReader = reader;
    }

    public List<TradeInfo> ProcessFile()
    {
        var rows = _textReader.ReadLine().Split(new[] { ',' }).Take(4);
        return FeedMapper(rows.ToList());
    }

    private List<TradeInfo> FeedMapper(List<String> rows)
    {
        var row = rows.Take(4).ToList();
        var trades = new List<TradeInfo>();
        trades.Add(new TradeInfo { TradeId = row[0], FutureValue = Convert.ToInt32(row[1]), NotionalValue = Convert.ToInt32(row[3]), PresentValue = Convert.ToInt32(row[2]) });
        return trades;
    } 
}
```

and then Mock using Rhino Mock

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Test]
    public void Test_Extract_First_Row_Mocked()
    {            
        //Arrange
        List<TradeInfo> listExpected = new List<TradeInfo>();
        var tradeInfo = new TradeInfo() { TradeId = "0453", FutureValue = 2000000, PresentValue = 3000000, NotionalValue = 400000 };
        listExpected.Add(tradeInfo);
        var textReader = MockRepository.GenerateMock<TextReader>();
        textReader.Expect(tr => tr.ReadLine()).Return("0453, 2000000, 3000000, 400000");
        var fileParser = new FileParser(textReader);
        var list = fileParser.ProcessFile();           
        listExpected.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(list);         

    }
}
```

BUT the question lies in the fact whether it is a good practice to pass such an object from the client code rather I feel it should be managed with using within the class responsible for processing. I agree with the idea of using a sep delegate for the actual code and one for the unit testing but again that is a bit of extra code in production. I may be a bit lost with the idea of dependency injection and mocking to even file IO open/read which actually is not a candidate for unit testing but the file processing logic is which can be tested by just passing the string content of the file (AAA23^YKL890^300000^TTRFGYUBARC).

Any ideas please! Thanks